# LightGBM does not accept the dtypes of my data

Tags: python, pandas, lightgbm, dtype

I'm trying to use LGBMClassifier and for some reason, he does not accept the types of my data (all features are not accepted, I tested it).

When we look at my data we can clearly see that all dtypes are either category, float or int (pd.DataFrame.info())

```
dtypes: category(275), float64(115), int64(9)
```

When I eventually try to train my LGBMClassifier I get the follwoing Error:

```
ValueError: Series.dtypes must be int, float or bool
```

Has anyone an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the error:

```
ValueError: Series.dtypes must be int, float or bool
```

refers in my case to the label, thus to the only passed series to the lgb.train() method. My label had the type category which can not be handled by lgb.train(). I had to change the dtype from 'category' to 'int'. Then It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Features with data type category are handled separately in LGBM. When you create the dataset for training you use the keyword categorical_feature for these features. This can look like this for example.
First you can store all features with type category in a list

```
categoricals = ["feature1", "feature2",...]
```

Then you use the list when creating the training data set for the LGBM model:

```
lgb_train = lgb.dataset(train_X,train_y,categorical_feature=categoricals)
```

The same you can do for the test data set for the LGBM model:

```
lgb_test = lgb.Dataset(test_X,test_y,categorical_feature=categoricals)
```